# string split and subquery in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

first of all i have 1 table in database.

**1)tags :**

```
id    name
1     theme1=test1
2     theme1=test2
3     theme1=test3
4     theme2=test1
5     theme2=test2
6     theme2=test3
```

And i have bunch of `id` of `tags` in array. like 1,3.

Now,

1)select name from tags where id=1

**result: theme1=test1**

(now using wildcard)

2)select id from tags where name like 'theme_test1'

**result : 1,4**

(here 'theme_test1' need to take from query1)

I am getting output proper but need to use 2 query.I want to do this in single query.

Thanks

Comment: So what you have done for the single query?

Comment: i used 2 query above to get output of second query.so i need to perform that task in one query

Comment: `theme1=test1` or `theme_test1`

Comment: here '_' is wildcard character, so output will return 2 records

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ? Do you just need the second result or what ?

Comment: according to id, ined to first select name of that id, then select similar name with id that contain similar name of previous query output.

Comment: you could use a subquery with REPLACE function to manipulate the 1st result, but 2 queries are probably fine, subqueries can be slow in mysql

Comment: yes @Steve but i have no idea how can i use subquery in this condition.

Comment: Or better yet normalize your database. If you have to start messing with string manipulation in your queries its a pretty good sign you need to refactor

Comment: How do you define similar. Is the wildcard alway at the same position ?

Comment: yes you right @Steve but i have very large amount of records in table, and also this records using by other codes also. so i have to change that also.

Comment: @v.eigler yes wildcard will be at same position always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name LIKE ( 
    SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(name,1,5),'__',SUBSTRING(name,8)) FROM tags WHERE id=1 
)
```

Returns 1,4

But Two queries (or a refactor) might be a better option

Comment: i think i have to use 2 query now

Comment: @SanketSorathiya Oops, syntax error, see ammendment

Answer (score 0):

If you whant to get the id with the same value you can try this:

```
SELECT t2.* FROM yourtable t1
JOIN youtable t2 on ON  t2.name like concat(substr(t1.name,1,5), '%', substr(t1.name,8))
WHERE t1.id=1;
```

Comment: maybe you must use % instead of _

Answer (score 0):

For performance better use this:

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM r 
INNER JOIN r AS t ON t.name LIKE CONCAT('theme_=test', SUBSTRING(r.name,-1))
WHERE r.id = '1'
```

`r` is your table in this case.

**NOTE**: this answer isn't valid in case that you have theme1=test1 and theme1=test10 values.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use query :

select id from tags where name = (select name from tags where id = 1 ).

You can try that query.